# How to serve POST request to http://domain_name.com using ASP.NET using a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, post

I need to serve POST requests to `http://domain_name.com` using custom code (i.e. controller)

I understand that I can configure to serve POST requests to a route like

```
http://domain_name.com/api/SomeController/id
```

using

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( 
    name: "DefaultApi", 
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}", 
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

But I want to serve POST request to `http://domain_name.com`

How do I do that ?

Please do not downvote without pointing me to answer or a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map some controller as default

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new {controller="values", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: for default root remove "api/" prefix and set default controller.